# Prevent Junit output to be printed in Gradle test reports

Tags: junit, gradle

Is there a way to prevent the
`<system-out><![CDATA ... ]]></system-out>` to be included in the junit reports when using gradle java plugin and the test task ?

I run a lot of tests with heavy outputs, and generating the HTML report results in a Java Heap space.

The report generation is done by ant with the `junit report` task for the moment.
I'm integrating gradle in a heavy ant script, and it will take time to move everything to gradle.

During the transition phase, I would like to keep the junit report generation provided by Ant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no way to prevent system out from showing up in Gradle's JUnit reports. However, if reporting is done in Ant, you can disable Gradle's JUnit reports.